# UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent does not work in iOS 6

Tags: status, ios6

In iOS 6:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

The status bar is shown in black, it is not in 0.5 alpha.
How to set the status bar to UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent in iOS6 please?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using storyboards, make sure that you tick "Wants Full Screen" in your view controllers. That will size your views so that it goes under the translucent status bar.

It looks like Xcode 4.5.2 is creating new view controllers in Storyboards with "Wants Full Screen" unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    # define STATUS_STYLE UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
    #else
    # define STATUS_STYLE UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent
    #endif

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:STATUS_STYLE animated:YES];
```